# Using the value in one array to set the object in another

Tags: c#, arrays

I am stuck trying to figure out how to use the values of one array of numbers to initialize a second array of objects. This might not be the most effective way to do something like this in a real program, but I am just trying to understand how to create a relationship between two different arrays.
    The first array is just a randomly generated array holding values 0,1 or 2. The second array is an array of Occupant objects. Each occupant has an occupant id that will be either 0, 1 or 2. I am trying to generate the second array of occupants by copying the values of first array and then initializing the second based on the occupant id. 
    Nothing I have tried will compile, and I can't think of anything else on my own except writing a million if statements. Surely there must be a simple solution I am missing. Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

FYI: Occupant is the base class, three classes derive from it, each with a unique id number.

```
static public class Board
{
    static public Occupant[,] board = BoardGen();
    static private Occupant[,] BoardGen()
    {
        Random myRandom = new Random();
        int[,] setup = new int[10, 10];
        for (int i = 0; i < setup.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < setup.GetLength(1); j++)
                setup[i, j] = myRandom.Next(0, 3);
        }

        Occupant[,] populate = new Occupant[10,10];

        // How to link setup to populate using the number to choose an occupant based on it's id number?

        return populate;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "I am trying to generate the second array of occupants by copying the values of first array and then initializing the second based on the occupant id" You'll need to elaborate. What is the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to fill-in the second table along with the first, or even better, completely forget about the first table:

```
    static private Occupant[,] BoardGen()
    {
        Random myRandom = new Random();

        // Not needed
        // int[,] setup = new int[10, 10];

        Occupant[,] populate = new Occupant[10, 10];

        for (int i = 0; i < populate .GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < populate .GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                int randomSetup = myRandom.Next(0, 3);

                switch (randomSetup)
                {
                    case 0:
                        populate[i, j] = new Occupant_0(); // Derived Class with id=0
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        populate[i, j] = new Occupant_1(); // Derived Class with id=1
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        populate[i, j] = new Occupant_2(); // Derived Class with id=2
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return populate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Master
{
    public abstract int Id { get; }
}

class A : Master
{
    public override int Id => 1;
}
class B : Master
{
    public override int Id => 2;
}
class C : Master
{
    public override int Id => 3;
}    

Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C) };
int[] yourIds = new int[100];
Master[] generated = new Master[yourIds.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < yourIds.Length; i++)
{
    generated[i] = (Master)Activator.CreateInstance(types[yourIds[i] - 1]);
}
```

I cannot understand your question completely, but this logic should fit your situation.

The point is that you can create an instance in runtime with the `System.Activator` and a `System.Type`.